# How to auto update a application when computer reset everytime it shuts down?

Tags: c#, wpf, auto-update

I have a **desktop application** made in WPF. I have seen third party tools to auto update my application easily, but I haven't seen a solution when a computer reset his files automatically.

We can ask the system administrator to install my application and everytime the computer reset, the application is still there. But, if I want to update my application, I have to go ask the system administrator again to update my application because as far as I know, the application cannot update itself.

**So is there a solution for auto-updating the application by itself without asking the system administrator to do it? I'm not necessarily (but it could be) asking for a coding solution, but if the system administrator can do something about it to solve the problem, that could be a solution too.**

Comment: Auto-update means to update to the latest version of the app itself? And what do you mean by Computer Reset? Did you mean re-start?

Comment: Yes for the first question, the second I'm not sure. What I mean by reset is when a computer restarts, the files that you installed on the computer are gone and only the necessary files (which are defined by the system administrator) are there.

Comment: Then its pretty simple. If you have a network, Keep the main application in a main server (in shared folder). Make an application whose sole purpose would be to fetch the file from the network folder and update the current one. keep this application in Windows Startup folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, one way would be to :

Keep your main app in a shared folder of the main server, which can be accessed by all the connected computers on which a user might use your app.

Make a second application which can access and copy your application from the network source. This code might help you to start with:

```
string MainAppPath = @"\\NetworkLocation\myMainApp.exe";
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();
File.Copy(MainAppPath , @"D:\UserFolder", true);
```

Ask your system admin to add this application in windows StartUp Folder with full rights.

Now every time the computer starts your application will be updated to the latest version that you will keep in the network folder